# weblogic 12.2.1 config wizard C:\Program is not recognized error

Tags: configuration, dns, weblogic

Running the Config Wizard via the start menu (Windows 7) simply fails.  Running it from the command prompt shows the infamous

`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

I know this is due to the space in "Program Files" (`dir C:\pro* /x` doesn't show `C:\Progra~1`).

The solution I've found for this is to replace `C:\Program Files\...` with `"C:\Program Files\..."`.

My question is this:
Since the WebLogic config wizard runs from `config.cmd`, which is loaded with variables for path names, do I have to update Windows system environment variable `PATH` and put quotes around all path names that have a space (since I don't know what WebLogic is looking for)?

Update:

I tried this and received `Files was unexpected at this time.`  Which made me think I was off with the quotes, but they are paired properly around every path with `C:\Program Files`.  A search on this error resulted with [this advice](http://davidngos.blogspot.com/2014/05/weblogic-install-files-was-unexpected.html)...basically the double quotes are the cause.

If the lack of quotes causes the first problem, and the presence of quotes causes the second problem, what to do?  It's a loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed another JDK in a location with no spaces (still got the error because I didn't change any environment variables because work site will change them back, breaking things).

[The install docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/lifecycle/12.2.1.3/wlsig/creating-and-configuring-weblogic-domain.html#GUID-4AECC00D-782D-4E77-85DF-F74DD61391B4) in chapter 4 say:

> To begin domain configuration, navigate to the
>   ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin directory and start the
>   Configuration Wizard.
>
> On UNIX operating systems:
>
> `./config.sh`
>
> On Microsoft Windows operating systems:
>
> `.\config.cmd`

Which implied at a command prompt (to me anyways).  I was reading another site for help and the guy said to update config.cmd to point it to new JDK location instead of JAVA_HOME.

Instead of right clicking on config.cmd to edit it I double clicked it and lo and behold...this nice domain creator GUI opened up where I could specify which JDK to use.  Done!  No errors...

If that little tidbit were in the docs it would've save me a lot of time and frustration.  And no, I'm not a server admin type, just a dev who needed a local web server for testing purposes.

I hope this helps someone.